# Why does ProgressDialog starts showing after executing its all the statements next to it?

Tags: android

I need to show the ProgressDialog **immediately after clicking login button**. But it starts showing only at the end of function.

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final ProgressDialog progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading", "Please wait");
        //HTTP Request within try catch goes here
        Log.i("HTTP Response",response);
        //list of statements goes here
        //list of statements goes here
        Log.i("MainActivity","All Statements Completed");
    }
});
```

Comment: I would use an `AsyncTask` and it's `onProgressUpdate` to do this.

Comment: The reason an AsyncTask is needed, is because the `ProgressDialog.show()` cannot access the UI thread while there is an httpRequest waiting to finish on it. A request like that will 'freeze' your UI thread until it completes. You really should read [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads) to get a better idea of why your thread is not responding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your comments in code suggest that you will be making an Http Request for login. So, you will be needing a AsyncTask.

In your AsyncTask, you can show progress dialog in `onPreExecute()` and dismiss it in `onPostExecute()`.

```
class YourAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>
{
    protected void onPreExecute (){
        Log.d("PreExceute","On pre Exceute.. show dialog box here");
        ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(yourActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("loading");
        pd.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void...arg0) {
        Log.d("DoINBackGround","On doInBackground...");


        return "You are at PostExecute";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d(""+result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

OnClick of loginbtn, create a AsyncTask and do your http request in doInBackground method, in onPreExecute start your progressBar and in postExecute stop progressBar.

Answer (score 1):

displaying a Dialog involves manipulation of children of window manager , which is basically a big UI manipulation. Your onClick method is running in UI thread, so when you add a new window/dialog it is not added to UI hierarchy immediately, it wait for the UI thread to be free, which of course will be at the end of ur on click method. The usual solution to this is using a AsynTask as mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use AsynTask like given..  in preExecute show the ProgressDialog and after doing your stuff like i do .. and dismiss the progressbar onPostExecute.. when you have done your work like you are doing

do this stuff in backgroudn..

```
//HTTP Request within try catch goes here
        Log.i("HTTP Response",response);
        //list of statements goes here
        //list of statements goes here
        Log.i("MainActivity","All Statements Completed");
```

do the above stuff in background..

```
class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{   
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(PlayListActivity.this,
                "Loading...", "Please wait...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        String HTML_response="";

        try {

            URL url = new URL(urls[0]); //enter your url here which to download
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null)
              {
                    // System.out.println(inputLine);
                 HTML_response += inputLine;
              }
                br.close();

                Parser(HTML_response);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            return HTML_response;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String feed)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(feed);

        progressDialog.dismiss();

        PlayListAdapter adapter = new PlayListAdapter(
                PlayListActivity.this, list);

        list_of_songs.setAdapter(adapter);

        Utilities.hideSoftKeyboard(PlayListActivity.this);


    }
}
```